# How to add own translator loader/filetype/"logic" to Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony project I want to add mulitple mail templates in my resources folder.

Filepath pattern:

```
app/Resources/translations/emails/[LOCALE]/[mail-type].html.twig
```

I've got my loader, named `MailLoader` witch load():

```
public function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages')
{
    $messages = [];
    $label = strstr(basename($resource), '.', true);

    $messages[$label] = file_get_contents($resource);

    $catalogue = new MessageCatalogue($locale);
    $catalogue->add($messages, $domain);

    return $catalogue;
}
```

I want to use `$translator->trans('mail-type');` to get specifc for locale content of file.

It's work when I do it like this:

```
    $translator = new Translator('pl');
    $translator->addLoader('mails', new MailLoader());

    $finder = new Finder();
    $finder->files()->in(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/views/email/pl');//->name('*.html.twig');

    foreach ($finder as $file) {
        $translator->addResource('mails', $file->getPath() . '/' . $file->getFilename(), 'pl');
    }

    echo $translator->trans('order-closed');//Returns file content.
```

But I want to extend Symfony Translator in container to use it everywhere I need. How to do it?

Please, I work wit this soo long. It's my first work with this Symfony Component and... It's made me crazy! >:D

Comment: Take a look at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html first, I think your approach could be simplified a lot.

Comment: @Yonel I've read docs. What do you suggest? I need to have separate folders for each location, with all emails templates. For registration, password change...